# SQL Server 2008 R2 Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

I know there have been a plethora of Q's asked around this but after reading, nobody seems to have the same trouble as I do.

Background Info: I am looking to doing incremental updates into a Cube, but have no timestamp of update on the table. I now am looking at creating a standalone table which updates via a trigger with the gkey and current datetime stamp, when a record is updated.

My trigger on the table is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdateVisitDetails ON  [visit_details]
FOR UPDATE
AS  
begin
   declare @VD_Gkey nvarchar
   declare @today DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()

   insert into [UpdatedVD]
     SELECT 
        @VD_Gkey, @today
     FROM 
        [visit_details]
End
```

This gives me an output like below but with 917 lines of the same:

```
+---------+-------------------------+
| VD_Gkey |          today          |
+---------+-------------------------+
| NULL    | 2014-01-02 11:21:23.963 |
| NULL    | 2014-01-02 11:21:23.963 |
+---------+-------------------------+
```

I know it's going to be something pretty simple but I cannot get my head around this.

Any help would be brilliant.

Thanks.

Comment: Your trigger isn't referring to either the `Inserted` or `Deleted` pseudo tables which contain the information about those rows that were actually affected by the `UPDATE` operation... you need to **join** against either of those two pseudo tables to limit your `INSERT` statement to those rows that were **actually updated** !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to access the [`inserted` and `deleted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) pseudo-tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterUpdateVisitDetails ON  [visit_details]
FOR UPDATE
AS  
begin
    insert into 
        [UpdatedVD]
    SELECT 
        i.VD_Gkey, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM
        inserted i;
End
```

Comment: Since it is an update trigger, and I'm assuming `VD_Gkey` is a PK which won't be updated, it doesn't really matter here whether you use `inserted` or `deleted`. Obviously, in the general case, `deleted` will contain the old values and `inserted` will contain the new values after the update.

Comment: @Lala: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.